# GTX 970, nvidia-settings stuck at performance Level 2 of 3 under load

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am using nvidia-settings version 381.22. After booting my pc my GTX 970 runs at it's full potential (power level 3). As soon as I put 100% load on it the power level is stuck at level 2. Regardless of my set preference.

How can I force my Nvidia card to always use power level 3, even if it's being loaded?

**GPU without load**
[image: GPU without load]

**GPU with load**
[image: GPU with load]

In neither of these cases it's hitting a temperature limit (at max it's 62°C).

Answer (score 0):

Folowing [this guide](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/increase-performance-gpu-boost-k80-autoboost/) helped me force the card to it's maximum clock speeds. Whatever Nvidia, whatever ...